# Numerical IVP Integrable Pole

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I am looking to numerically solve the ODE
$$\vec{Y^\prime}(z)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0& \frac{1}{\beta(z)\gamma(z)}\\-\frac{\gamma^{\prime\prime}(z)}{\beta(z)} & 0\end{array}\right]\cdot \vec{Y}(z),$$
where $\beta=\sqrt{1-1/\gamma^2}$ and $\beta(z)$ is the relativistic velocity as a function of position which is known beforehand.  This describes the transverse position of a beam of charged particles in an accelerating electric field.

My problem is that I care about solutions when $\beta(z=0) = 0$ when the coefficients of the ODE blow up.  For example, an electric field of the form $E_z(z) \propto 1+z$ yields $\beta(z)$ which when inserted gives:
$$\vec{Y^\prime}(z)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0& \frac{1}{\sqrt{z(8+8z+4z^2+z^3)}}\\-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-4/(2+2z+z^2)^2}} & 0\end{array}\right]\cdot \vec{Y}(z),$$
The upper right element clearly diverges preventing solution by numerical methods.

However, for similar analytically tractable cases, the equation can be solved and the pole integrated over symbolically.

**My question is: what is the name of this type of issue and is there any robust way of working around it?**

My current solution is to solve the problem with a different independent variable (physically interpreted as time here) $z^{\prime}(t)\propto\beta(t)$ which gives the numerically solvable equation:
$$\vec{Y^\prime}(t)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0& \frac{1}{\gamma(t)}\\-\gamma^{\prime\prime}(z(t)) & 0\end{array}\right]\cdot \vec{Y}(t),$$
with the additional component $z^{\prime}(t)= c\beta(t)$, of course.  The reason I don't like this solution is that I can't choose at what $z$ I receive the solution vector $\vec{Y}$, I only get it at the $t$ that I specify.

My other ideas were to solve for some sort of transformed version of $\vec{Y}$ or to make some prior known independent variable transform $z\to t^2$ which solves the problem as long as the electric field can be modeled as nearly linear at $z=0$, but now I have a known one to one map from $t$ to $z$ (for $t>0$ at least) and can pick the values I care about before numerically solving.

Comment: Some more progress: According to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSingularPoint.html) I am dealing with an ODE that has a **regular singular point** or **non-essential singularity** at $z=0$.  I still need help trying to numerically solve the IVP, however.

Comment: Another hint: the same problem is encountered in numerically solving Bessel's equation starting at $x=0$, so it isn't an uncommon issue.  However, I'm still not seeing great workarounds.